# MySQL unable to import SQL that creates procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, permissions

I am using a hosted web service account that uses `cpanel` as its management system. When logged into `phpmyadmin`, I am trying to import an SQL file that contains tables and some procedures.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getClientDashboardStatsMap` (IN `in_userID` INT)  BEGIN

        SELECT 
            rl.city,
            rl.state,
            rl.zip,
            rl.longitude,
            rl.latitude,
            rl.timestamp,
            count(rl.ID) as total
        FROM 
            crowd.redemption_log as rl
        JOIN
            reward as r
        ON 
            rl.rewardID = r.rewardID
        WHERE 
            r.userID = 1
        AND
            rl.timestamp BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
        GROUP BY
            rl.city, rl.state, rl.zip
        ORDER BY 
            total DESC;

END$$
```

When I try to run this, I get an error about needing super user privileges to do so. Doing some searching, people suggested removing the definer line like so:

`CREATE  PROCEDURE getClientDashboardStatsMap (IN in_userID INT)  BEGIN`.

While this allows me to complete the import, I am running into another issue. The procedures are getting a default definer of `cpaneluser@localhost`. However, the database user that is set up is different than this user so the procedure has no permissions for things like `select, update, delete`. The database user is `cpaneluser_dbusername`, which is typical for hosted sites like this so you can associate databases with accounts.

How else can I get this procedures to run, under the correct user? I don't see any settings in `PHPMYADMIN` for privileges in order to run these as a super user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this problem:

1. Log into `phpmyadmin` with the database user `cpaneluser_dbusername`. I am not familar with `phpmyadmin` and `cpanel`, so I'm not sure whether they provide you the option to change the user. You should check it out by yourself. I'm using MySQL Workbench and MySQL Administrator, they both privode me this option.
2. Grant privileges to `cpaneluser@localhost`. Such as:

   `GRANT ALL ON db_name.table_name TO 'cpaneluser@localhost';`

It's better if you grant each privilege explicitly, e.g.: `GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON ...`. Check [GRANT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html).